# What is the stability level of Oracle 11g? Is it suitable for production?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

We are using both Express edition and Commercial edition to power up a Distributed application. Is Oracle 11g a good candidate for this application since we need data synchronization? Or is Oracle 10G better for this purpose?

Comment: 11g was published five years ago, not yesterday.

Comment: The simple answer is, yes, Oracle 11g is suitable for production.  If you need further clarification for your specific circumstances (which you make no mention to here), you really should contact Oracle about it.

Answer (score 2):

What is "production ready"?

Is it supported by Oracle? - Yes.
Has it been around for a long time? - Yes.
Is it used in large-scale distributed implementations globally? - Yes.

Premier support for all versions of 10g has ended. Extended support for 10g ends July 2013. 11g is really your only choice anyway if you need to use Oracle.